# Showing and Running Python Codes in a Website for Students

Tags: python

Is there any website which I can show my Python codes to the students and they can run them in my website? I'm looking for a free version.

There are some websites about it but they don't run the code.

https://highlight.hohli.com/

https://highlightjs.org/

This website has it: https://www.educative.io/courses/learn-python-3-from-scratch/B82NOXwQKG2

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for services like [Juypter Notebooks online](https://jupyter.org/try), [Jetbrains Datalore](https://datalore.jetbrains.com/) or [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). There are many others as well.

Comment: No. I said I'm looking for my website. I know them already.

I will teach Python to students and searching like this: https://www.educative.io/courses/learn-python-3-from-scratch/B82NOXwQKG2

Check it. There is a run button under the codes.

Comment: There are a few tools which transpile Python to JavaScript so it can be executed in the browser a few of which are described in this [blog post](https://yasoob.me/2019/05/22/running-python-in-the-browser/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) and make a Jupyter notebook there.